# How to link Dafny code with a C# assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, dafny

I'm trying to build and run an [example program by James Wilcox that combines Dafny code and C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470751/94977). I'm using `mono` on a Mac. The build command in that answer doesn't work for me:

```
$ dafny fileiotest.dfy fileionative.cs
Dafny 3.0.0.20820

Dafny program verifier finished with 4 verified, 0 errors
Compiled program written to fileiotest.cs
Errors compiling program into fileiotest
(8,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(9,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(28,28): error CS0012: The type 'TextWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

(43,28): error CS0012: The type 'TextWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

(58,28): error CS0012: The type 'TextWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

(73,28): error CS0012: The type 'TextWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

(87,28): error CS0012: The type 'TextWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

(1858,18): error CS0117: 'FileStream' does not contain a definition for 'Open'

(1870,23): error CS1061: 'FileStream' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'FileStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I "add a reference to assembly"? Can it be done on the `dafny` command line?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the System.Net imports for the file example, so you can just delete those includes from the `fileionative.cs` file.

I am not sure about the `TextWriter` errors, but if you can figure out what assembly reference you need, you can add it to the command line by running `csc` manually. This is what worked on my machine:

```
dafny fileiotest.dfy /spillTargetCode:3 /compile:0
csc fileionative.cs fileiotest.cs /r:System.Core.dll /r:System.dll /r:System.Collections.Immutable.dll /r:System.Runtime.dll /r:System.Numerics.dll
```

The `/spillTargetCode:3` argument tells Dafny to output the `fileiotest.cs` file. The `/compile:0` line tells it to skip the final compilation step, so you can do it manually.

Finally, for your last two errors:

```
(1858,18): error CS0117: 'FileStream' does not contain a definition for 'Open'

(1870,23): error CS1061: 'FileStream' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'FileStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I believe this is a Dafny version mismatch thing with the conventions expected of Dafny-generated C# code. The `fileionative.cs` from the other stack overflow answer uses a namespace called `__default`, but the Dafny-generated `fileiotest.cs` uses a namespace called `_module`. So you just need to change `fileionative.cs` to use the correct namespace `_module` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, there really were several problems here.

Comment: I'm still not able to compile this. I get a message "You must add a reference to assembly 'nestandard, Version=2.0.0.0...'". But `/r:netstandard.dll` results in "error CS0006: Metadata file 'netstandard.dll' could not be found".

Comment: What `dotnet` does is just supply absolute paths for all the DLLs, and  it *does* include a reference to netstandard.dll on its command line, just by default. So this may work for me—but I don't have time to try it out just now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is beyond my knowledge of C# / .net / mono, sorry :\