# Can one prove that "hello, world" printed in two different ways has the same effect in Dafny?

Tags: io, dafny

It seems intuitively clear that the effect of the following two methods are identical, if one ignores intermediate stages:

```
method print1()
{
    print "hello, world\n";
}

method print2()
{
    print "hello, ";
    print "world";
    print "\n";
}
```

Is there a way to assert the equivalence of side effects for these two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no builtin way to do this.

Even if there was, it wouldn't support the many operations *not* built in to Dafny that are needed to connect a program to the real world, such as reading input.

If you want to do something like that, the way to do it is to build a logical model of the aspects of the side effect that you care about capturing, and then axiomatize the fact that the primitive operations satisfy their specifications.

(You might find [this unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350916/reading-from-writing-to-files-in-dafny) about file IO useful as a starting point, but it does not address the question of logical modeling.)

Comment: Are you aware of any verification systems that support this, say Frama C?

Comment: No, and in fact, in the most common logical model I am aware of (tracking the sequence of system calls made), these two programs are not equivalent, because they make different sequences of system calls.