# How to do keyboard input in Dafny?

Tags: input, io, keyboard, dafny

Can anyone give me an example of a simple Dafny program, like reading two integers from the keyboard and output their sum?

I want to use Dafny for a programming course at our university, but then I really need I/O.
I found 'print' for output, but cannot find anything for input.

There must be some (obvious) way to do this, right?

I searched questions tagged I/O, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a canonical method for that. Dafny is not really used in that way often. In theory it can be done. There was a similar question here.
[Reading from (Writing to) files in Dafny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350916/reading-from-writing-to-files-in-dafny)

Basically, you create references to external functions that are in the host target language and use those. Note the C sharp fileionative.cs in that repo.

http://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef.html#sec-compilation

Answer (score 0):

I created a console version of the file io answer [here](https://github.com/wilcoxjay/notes/blob/master/consoleio.dfy) and [here](https://github.com/wilcoxjay/notes/blob/master/consoleionative.cs). You can then run `dafny consoleio.dfy consoleionative.cs` and it will ask you your name and greet you.

If you want to parse an integer, you would need to either call a native function to do that, or write Dafny code to convert a string to an integer. If you tell me which of these approaches you prefer, I can try to extend the example with them.